# Your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',)' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

When I am calling a mysql stored procedure parameters the error mentioned in the title is thrown.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('desplay_errors','1');

//Connect to the database
    $host = "127.0.0.1";
    $user = "root";                     //Your Cloud 9 username
    $pass = "";                         //Remember, there is NO password by default!
    $db = "mydata_db";                  //Your database name you want to connect to

    $connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass)or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("mydata_db",$connection);

 if(isset($_POST["Login"]))
  {
   $user= mysql_real_escape_string($_post['user']);
   $emailid= mysql_real_escape_string($_post['emailid']);
   $password= mysql_real_escape_string($_post['password']);
   insertinfo($user,$emailid,$password);
   } 
   function insertinfo($user,$emailid,$password)
   {
   //$retval=mysql_query("call sp_login('testing','testing@gmail.com','testing');");    //it is working   

$retval=mysql_query("call sp_login($user,$emailid,$password)"); //it is not working giving error
    if(! $retval ) {
    die('Could not enter data:'. mysql_error());
  }
    echo "Entered data successfully\n";

  }   
?>

<form method="post" action="connect.php" >
<div  style="text-align:center;right:20%; margin-top:2cm;  background-color: yellow; color:red;" >
<h7><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<u>Login</u></b></h7> <br/>
User: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  <input type="text" name="user"><br/><br/>
Emailid:&nbsp; <input type="text" name="emailid">&nbsp;<br/><br/>
Password:<input TYPE="text" name="password">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login">
<input type="submit" name="Home" value="Home">&nbsp;
</div>
</form>
```

What is wrong in calling stored procedure and passing parameters?

The error message is:

> Could not enter data: you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',)' at line 1

Comment: I would suggest to look for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php) or [MySqli](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.mysqli.php) instead of the deprecated mysql_query. Instead of trying to debug this...

Comment: The only thing I see... Is that *maybe* you are testing your script without a password... Testing shortcuts often cause weird bugs ;).  If `$password` is empty, this could result in a `,)` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line

```
$retval=mysql_query("call sp_login($user,$emailid,$password)");
```

to this

```
$retval=mysql_query("call sp_login('$user','$emailid','$password')");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no variable `$_post` in PHP, it's called `$_POST`

Change your lines to this:

```
$user= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$emailid= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emailid']);
$password= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

Currently all your variables you use in the query are empty (hence the resulting query `,)`, a comma directly followed by the closing bracket).

Additionally you have to place the string variables in quotes, as noted by amaksr:

```
"call sp_login('$user','$emailid','$password')"
```

It is always good to echo the actual generated query when you have a syntax error.

And the obligatory note: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, they have been removed from PHP 7, your code will stop working when you upgrade to that version. You should not write new code using them, use [`mysqli_*` or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

One last thing: The ini setting is called `display_errors`, not `desplay_errors`. If you had set this correctly you would have gotten some notices saying the variables aren't there.